# Is there a free tool that can set the file time to match the camera time in jpg meta data?

Tags: metadata, jpeg

I have a bunch of pictures for which something went wrong during the import (I used Image Capture on Mountain Lion) went wrong and the file time is completely random. The correct time when the picture was taken is stored in the meta data. Since Picasa orders photos by file time rather than what is set in the meta data, they are ordered incorrectly now.

Is there a free tool that can modify the file time to match the camera time in the meta data for all these pictures easily?

Comment: @mattdm My answer below is a superset of the answer you cite (I note after starting it). I have put a slightly modified copy as an answer on the question you cited. Suggestions as to how best rationalise this?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon My suggestion is to delete this one and answer on on the other thread. I'll vote you up over there. This one is on the verge of being closed as a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Irfanview and jhead will both do what you want.**
Both free.
Links to both below.
jhead is command line driven or can be called by other processes.
Irfanview version can be invoked from a command line or internally in a batch or on a file by file basis.

---

**Irfanview** allows command line or batch or per file date/time transfer from EXIF to file spec or vice versa (with no other file changes if so desired).

**Source:** Free from **www.irfanview.com**

**Batch "save with original date/time".**
This will set file date and time to camera EXIF values.

- File / batch / Add all.
  Advanced / Save files with original date/time

**From command line** - this is a "rotate" with NO action except to copy date/time from EXIF to file date and time. The opposite can also be achieved if desired. :

- i_view32.exe file_spec\*.jpg /jpg_rotate=(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

To copy date/time in opposite direction ((filespec to EXIF) use as above with (0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)

---

**jhead** will do just about anything you can imagine with jpeg files

**Source:** Free from **http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/**

I use a batch file as below. Other options are possible:

- jhead -ft *%1*.jpg

They say: Things jhead can modify in an exif jpeg file

- Up-right images according to rotation tag using jpegtran
  Set or relative adjust internal exif timestamps
  Fix date / time offsets in large batches of images
  **Re-name or date stamp files according to exif timestamp**
  Transfer exif headers between images
  Replace thumbnails inside Exif headers
  Edit jpeg comments (but not the Exif comments)
  Delete exif or comment sections from jpeg images
  Create new minimal exif header containing date and thumbnail